# Issues with glow while dragging an Object

Tags: raphael

I have a rectangle which glows on mousedown event & glow disappears at mouseup event. The issue is when I drag the rectangle, the glow persists on the canvas!

Here's my code for clarity:

```
window.onload = function(){
        var paper = new Raphael("holder",500,500);

        var myRect = paper.rect(200,200,200,100,10);
        myRect.attr({
            fill: "#999",
            stroke: "#555",
            'stroke-width': 5
        });

        myRect.mousedown(function(){
                this.g = myRect.glow();
            }
        );
        myRect.mouseup(function(){
                this.g.remove();
        });
        var start = function(){
            this.ox = this.attr('x');
            this.oy = this.attr('y');
        },
        move = function(dx,dy){
            var att = {x:this.ox+dx,y:this.ox+dy};
            this.attr(att);
        },
        up = function(){
            //
        };
        myRect.drag(move,start,up);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use `this` inside an anonymous function because the scope of `this` is just available in there.

Second, you don't need `myRect.mousedown` and `myRect.mouseup` because you handle those we the callbacks inside your `myRect.drag` (`start` and `up`)

So i made you a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GztWJ/) where you can see it working.

**P.S.** There seems to be another bug with the positioning: when you drag a few times the rectangle gets shifted away from the cursor.

Comment: I'll fix the bug wrt positioning, yours is alot improved one than my version but in your fiddle as you can see that the glow stays at the previous position of the rectangle & disappears only after we unclick it....I kinda want it to travel along with my rectangle...Anyways Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the glow of the object on `start` and apply it again on `up`. In this way the shadow wont be visible while you're draggin the object but will be there when you'll drop the object.

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvUJK/1/)** with your example.

Comment: This is much better approach, although there are some issues with the dragging part though, Thanks :)